# Django error path does not exist. Static files sometimes do not load

Tags: django, django-templates, django-staticfiles

I have a weird problem with my app in Django.
The link for the app is [www.mativated.com](http://www.mativated.com).
The problem is - sometimes the app loads normally, but very often, some static files do not load - that's why it looks like page is bugged.
These are the logs.

I am using Whitenoise to serve files in development.
My settings are:

```
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage'
```

I checked the file logo.removebg, and whenever it appears it is called correctly - like this
`src="{% static 'main/img/logo-removebg.png' %}">`
Collectstatic does not help.

I've been fighting with all these static files since one month, I am looking for any help, advice.
I can give you access to files, or give more specific informations.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/srv52965/virtualenv/main/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/home/srv52965/virtualenv/main/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/home/srv52965/virtualenv/main/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 40, in serve
    raise Http404(_("\u201c%(path)s\u201d does not exist") % {"path": fullpath})
django.http.response.Http404: \u201c/home/srv52965/main/staticfiles/main/img/logo-removebg.png\u201d does not exist

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/srv52965/virtualenv/main/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 880, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[bit]
TypeError: 'URLResolver' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/srv52965/virtualenv/main/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 890, in _resolve_lookup
    current = getattr(current, bit)
AttributeError: 'URLResolver' object has no attribute 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/srv52965/virtualenv/main/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 896, in _resolve_lookup
    current = current[int(bit)]
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/srv52965/virtualenv/main/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 903, in _resolve_lookup
    raise VariableDoesNotExist(
django.template.base.VariableDoesNotExist: Failed lookup for key [name] in <URLResolver <module 'allauth.urls' from '/home/srv52965/virtualenv/main/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/allauth/urls.py'> (None:None) 'account/'>

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/alt/python38/lib64/python3.8/logging/__init__.py", line 1088, in emit
    stream.write(msg + self.terminator)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u201c' in position 602: ordinal not in range(128)
Call stack:
  File "/home/srv52965/virtualenv/main/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/whitenoise/base.py", line 81, in __call__
```

Comment: `Http404(_("\u201c%(path)s\u201d does not exist")` here [u201c](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201c/index.htm) + [u201d](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201d/index.htm) are fancy quotation marks `“”` . Replace them in your code with ASKII `"` symbol.

Comment: @IvanStarostin but where is it? This is Django code, not mine

Comment: Django code fails trying to handle what you gave to him. Please use search. The problem is in your codebase.